# How to remove spikes in solution and produce smooth interpolation with scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, interpolation, numerical-computing

I'm writing a numerical solution to a partial integro-differential equation, and I need it to run quickly so I found that scipy.integrate.simps is best, but it's not always 100% accurate and produces the spikes in [1]. My solution was to remove them with scipy.signal.medfilt and then interpolate over the gaps with an interpolator (I've tried CubicSpline, PChipInterpolator, scipy.interp1d, akima,...) but all of them produce little "hiccups" in the solution that can be seen at y=0.1, (produced with 3rd order butterworth filter) and these errors grow as the solution is evolved. How do I remove the spikes and get a simple, smooth interpolation over the gaps? Thanks!

Comment: What is your data? I see a logarithmic x-scale, which to me indicates your x-values are not (roughly) linearly spaced. Can you add some example x-y data to your question; plus the code you're executing?

Comment: @9769953 I've attached sample data and code!

Comment: I think you need to do a little more work to make your example reproducible. We should be able to copy/paste the code into a notebook or script, execute it, and see the issues you're describing

Comment: Where does FORTRAN come in? Are you comparing to a result computed with FORTRAN? What code was used for that?

Comment: @9769953 ya the FORTRAN  code is just for comparison. It's not my code though. Although also tried wrapping the adaptive gaussian integrator that the FORTRAN code uses with f2py to use in my code instead of simps since the FORTRAN code runs much faster than mine but my code is still super slow just like it is with the scipy.dblquad

Answer (score 1):

I don't work with scipy, but from what I've gathered, some things stood out to me, and could possibly be what's causing problems.

- Your call to `plt.show()` which displays the data happens before you filter out the outliers with `medfilt()`, so the corrected data might not appear in your plot
- The median filter from what I gather doesn't remove outliers from your data, instead it resets each data point with the median value amongst its k-neighbors.
- With this in mind, I have two suggestions, (1) your median filter window might be too small, and that is causing the outliers to not be removed. Try setting it yourself using `medfilt(self.n_, k_size=5)`, it defaults to 3 so try odd numbers larger than 3. (2) Given that you're not losing data points from using the medfilter, you might not need the lines that follow it which try to interpolate data that was presumably removed.